# SwiftUI project running but can't archive

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, compiler-errors

I'm trying to archive my project for macOS.
Have some problem. I can run but can't archive the project.
Getting compiler error. Compiler tells me that can't fine all my ViewModels. Why?

[image]

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Impossible to debug without more information. Are you sure all of your source files are added to the correct target? Have you tried to clean your build folder and start from scratch?

Comment: Yes. All my files are in target. Checked it twice(

Comment: I can add some code, but there is nothing what can help. I can't understand why i can run but can't archive. I have no any special settings for archive. Everything by default

Comment: Solved: Nothing helps until I remove project from disk and pull it again